# How do I use SetTimer in non-dialog .cpp in my mfc app?

Tags: c++, mfc

My question is for normal mfc SetTimer, as follows

```
void CTimersDlg::OnButtonBegin()
{
    // create the timer

    SetTimer(m_nTimerID, uElapse, NULL);
}

void CTimersDlg::OnButtonStop()
{
    // destroy the timer
      KillTimer(m_nTimerID);
}

void CTimersDlg::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)  // called every uElapse milliseconds
{
    // do something, but quickly
    CDialog::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

but if I need to use SetTimer in non dialog.cpp, for example in my sender.cpp 
how do I create the timer? As in the SetTimer fields, the handler(callback) function?

Answer (score 5):

You can pass NULL as the window handle and include callback function in the call to `SetTimer`. This will allow you to receive timer notifications without associating it with a specific window.

If the timer is intended to be used in a separate "worker" thread (one without a window) you will still need to process the message queue in order to receive timer notifications. If you are creating a thread using a `CWinThread` object this is already handled for you in the default implementation of `CWinThread::Run`.

If you can update your question to include more information about the contents of `sender.cpp` I can provide a more suitable example. This uses the plain Windows API to create a timer and handle the required dispatch queue.

```
// Example only.
VOID CALLBACK timerCallback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime)
{
    printf("Timer called\n");
}

void SomeFunc()
{
    SetTimer(NULL, 1, 1000, timerCallback);

    MSG msg;

    // msg-pump
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SetTimer is associated with windows, you need windows handle to use it. For non window classes you should consider using [CreateWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or use [TimerQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: SetTimer() does not require a window. If you pass NULL as the HWND argument you must supply a pointer to a callback function to handle timer notifications. You still need to dispatch messages in the calling thread to receive notifications through the callback however.