# How to exit a thread's message loop?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, message-loop

A background-thread can be configured to receive window messages. You would post messages to the thread using [`PostThreadMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx). What's the correct way to exit that message loop?

### Background

Before you can post messages to a background thread, the thread needs to ensure that a message queue is created by calling `PeekMessage`:

```
procedure ThreadProcedure;
var
   msg: TMsg;
begin
   //Call PeekMessage to force the system to create the message queue.
   PeekMessage(msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);
end;
```

Now the outside world is able to post messages to our thread:

```
PostThreadMessage(nThreadID, WM_ReadyATractorBeam, 0, 0);
```

and our thread sits in a `GetMessage` loop:

```
procedure ThreadProcedure;
var
   msg: TMsg;
begin
   //Call PeekMessage to force the system to create the message queue.
   PeekMessage(msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);

   //Start our message pumping loop. 
   //GetMessage will return false when it receives a WM_QUIT

   //   GetMessage can return -1 if there's an error
   //   Delphi LongBool interprets non-zero as true.
   //   If GetMessage *does* fail, then msg will not be valid. 
   //   We want some way to handle that.
   //Invalid:
   //while (GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0)) do
   //Better:
   while LongInt(GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0)) > 0 do
   begin
      case msg.message of
      WM_ReadyATractorBeam: ReadyTractorBeam;

      // No point in calling Translate/Dispatch if there's no window associated.
      // Dispatch will just throw the message away
//    else
//       TranslateMessage(Msg);
//       DispatchMessage(Msg);
//    end;
   end;
end;
```

My question is what's the correct way to have `GetMessage` receive a `WM_QUIT` message and return false.

We've already learned [that the *incorrect* way to post a `WM_QUIT` message](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/04/489028.aspx) is to call:

```
PostThreadMessage(nThreadId, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
```

There is even [examples out there where people employ this approach](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225755/PostThreadMessage-Demystified). From MSDN:

> Do not post the **WM_QUIT** message using the [**PostMessage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function; use [**PostQuitMessage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The *correct* way is for "someone" to call [`PostQuitMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `PostQuitMessage` [is a special function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/11/04/489028.aspx), that sets the special flag associated with a message queue so that `GetMessage` will synthesize a `WM_QUIT` message when the time is right.

If this were a message loop associated with a "*window*", then the standard design pattern is when the window is being destroyed, and a `WM_DESTROY` message is received, we catch it and call `PostQuitMessage`:

```
procedure ThreadProcedure;
var
   msg: TMsg;
begin
   //Call PeekMessage to force the system to create the message queue.
   PeekMessage(msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);

   //Start our message pumping loop. 
   //GetMessage will return false when it receives a WM_QUIT
   while Longint(GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0)) > 0 do
   begin
      case msg.message of
      WM_ReadyATractorBeam: ReadyTractorBeam;
      WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0);
      end;
   end;
end;
```

Problem is that `WM_DESTROY` [is sent by the Window Manager. It is sent when someone calls `DestroyWindow`. It is wrong to just post `WM_DESTROY`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/09/26/10216420.aspx).

Now i *could* synthesize some artifical `WM_PleaseEndYourself` message:

```
PostThreadMessage(nThreadID, WM_PleaseEndYourself, 0, 0);
```

and then handle it in my thread's message loop:

```
procedure ThreadProcedure;
var
   msg: TMsg;
begin
   //Call PeekMessage to force the system to create the message queue.
   PeekMessage(msg, NULL, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE);

   //Start our message pumping loop. 
   //GetMessage will return false when it receives a WM_QUIT
   while Longint(GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0)) > 0 do
   begin
      case msg.message of
      WM_ReadyATractorBeam: ReadyTractorBeam;
      WM_PleaseEndYourself: PostQuitMessage(0);
      end;
   end;
end;
```

But is there a *canonical* way to exit a thread's message loop?

---

### But don't do this

It turns out that it's better for *everyone* that you **don't** use a windowless message queue. A lot of things can be unintentionally, and subtly, broken if you don't have a window for messages to be dispatched to.

[Instead allocate hidden window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/09/30/9901065.aspx) (e.g. using Delphi's [thread](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2007/06/allocatehwnd-is-not-thread-safe.html)-[unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820294/how-can-i-make-allocatehwnd-threadsafe) [`AllocateHwnd`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_AllocateHWnd.html)) and post messages to it using plain old [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
   msg: TMsg;
begin
   Fhwnd := AllocateHwnd(WindowProc);
   if Fhwnd = 0 then Exit;
   try
      while Longint(GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0)) > 0 do
      begin
         TranslateMessage(msg);
         DispatchMessage(msg);
      end;
   finally
      DeallocateHwnd(Fhwnd);
      Fhwnd := 0;
   end;
end;
```

Where we can have a plain old window procedure to handle the messages:

```
WM_TerminateYourself = WM_APP + 1;

procedure TMyThread.WindowProc(var msg: TMessage);
begin
   case msg.Msg of
   WM_ReadyATractorBeam: ReadyTractorBeam;
   WM_TerminateYourself: PostQuitMessage(0);
   else
      msg.Result := DefWindowProc(Fhwnd, msg.msg, msg.wParam, msg.lParam);
   end;
end;
```

and when you want the thread to finish, you tell it:

```
procedure TMyThread.Terminate;
begin
   PostMessage(Fhwnd, WM_TerminateYourself, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Once you have a special message, why bother with PostQuitMessage? Just get out of there.

Comment: David, PostQuitMessage is your ticket for getting out.

Comment: PostQuitMessage() probably does some other stuff. It seems possible that it purges the queue and forces subsequent submission attempts to fail?  Not sure.

Comment: What is the purpose of calling `TranslateMessage` - `DispatchMessage` if you have no window created in a thread?

Comment: Use Delphi `Break` operator to exit thread message loop, like any other loop.

Comment: @Dialectus break would be easier!

Comment: @Dialecticus, you don't need a ticket to get out. You're free to leave whenever you want.

Comment: Unlike the Hotel California!  ;-)

Comment: @Martin, it doesn't do anything else. It definitely doesn't purge the queue. All it does is set a flag, so the next time you call `GetMessage` and there aren't any other messages, it will return `wm_Quit`.

Comment: I think the PeekMessage call is superfluos.

Comment: @Sertac Correct, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx) makes it clear that calling `GetMessage` creates the message queue.

Comment: @David - Thanks, I looked for it to be certain but couldn't find..

Comment: @Serg i *thought* the purpose of calling `DispatchMessage` would be to ensure that i'm processing messages, so that COM still functions from within my thread. i don't know exactly *why* COM needs my thread to keep processing messages, or *how* COM works if i don't "*dispatch messages that aren't mine to the Windows ether*", but looks like calling `DispatchMessage` in a window-less message pump serves no purpose. i'll leave the code in, but commented out, so future me knows that calling `DispatchMessage` is wrong.

Comment: DispatchMessage is indeed needed if you're using COM. COM creates a hidden window for itself and sends messages there when marshaling cross-apartment calls to ensure methods are executed in the right thread.

Comment: You really need a thread window if you have 2 or more message loops in a thread, and as in oldnewthing article you don't control some loops; in this case a windowless message will be discarded if processed in wrong message loop, while a message with destination hWnd will be dispatched to the window procedure by `DispatchMessage`.

Comment: @RobKennedy - OK, thanks:) Luckily, I rarely use COM and so don't need to use Windows Message Queues for signalling to work threads.  I can't recollect ever calling PostQuitMessage() explicitly.

Comment: DDE is one example where you might have a windowless app that still requires a message loop. If it's written as a console app you need a way to pass the Ctrl+C signal onto the main thread. Yes, it's an edge case, but it's still a valid one :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no canonical way; there is no canon. You get `GetMessage` to return zero by posting a `wm_Quit` message, and you do that by calling `PostQuitMessage`. When and how you know to do that is up to you.

It common to do it in response to `wm_Destroy`, but that's only because the common way to exit programs is by closing windows. If you have no window to close, then choose a different way. Your `wm_PleaseEndYourself` idea is fine.

You don't even have to send a message. You could use some waitable object like an event or a semaphore, and then use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to detect whether it's signaled while also waiting for new messages.

You don't really even have to wait for `GetMessage` to return zero. If you already know the thread needs to stop, then you can simply stop processing messages entirely. There are lots of ways to exit a loop. You could use `exit`, `break`, `raise`, or even `goto`, or you could set a flag that you check in the loop condition along with the return value of `GetMessage`.

Note also that `GetMessage` returns -1 on failure, which as a non-zero value will be interpreted as true. You probably don't want to continue your message loop if `GetMessage` fails, so instead check for `GetMessage(...) > 0`, or do like [the documentation recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx).

Comment: Ahhh, i was confused because [`GetMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a `BOOL`. i'll update the question with a note about the *wrong* way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Using `PostThreadMessage` is not necessarily incorrect. Raymond's article that you linked to says:

> Because the system tries not to inject a WM_QUIT message at a "bad time"; instead it waits for things to "settle down" before generating the WM_QUIT message, thereby reducing the chances that the program might be in the middle of a multi-step procedure triggered by a sequence of posted messages.

If the concerns outlined here do not apply to your message queue, then call `PostThreadMessage` with `WM_QUIT` and knock yourself out. Otherwise you'll need to create a special signal, i.e. a user-defined message, that allows you to call `PostQuitMessage` from the thread.